# Number of ways of visiting N places

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A tourist wants to visit $N$ cities, each numbered from $1$ to $N$, but he wants to visit them in a *weird* order.

A *weird* order is such in which no city numbered $i$ is the $i$-th to visit in his travel itinerary.

He wants to visit each city exactly once.

What are the number of possible *weird* orders for his travel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering that the sequence in which he visits these $n$ cities, is $$a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$$ then $a_i \neq i$. This is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), whose formula is given by $$!n=\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$$ where $[x]$ is the nearest integer function and $!n$ is the number of derangements for an sequence with $n$ elements.

This sequence also appears in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A000166), which also provides you with recurrence relations, namely $$!n=(n-1)[!(n-1)+!(n-2)]$$for the number of derangements.

Answer (score 3):

Hint look up dearrangements. $D_n=N!(1-1\frac{1}{2!}...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!})$